# jQuery .after function is printing instead of moving?

Tags: jquery

I have some submenu items that I want to move on a mobile menu, so I'm moving the required `<li>`'s so that they are no longer children, but siblings. This keeps printing 'li.mftopmenu' instead of moving the elements. I have also tried `.insertafter`, but that just clones them, then moves them.

```
jQuery('li.mfsubmenu').after('li.mftopmenu');
```

Comment: Fixed!! Not as elegant, but I just numbered all the elements.

`jQuery('li.mfsubmenu1').insertAfter(jQuery('li.mftopmenu'));
  jQuery('li.mfsubmenu2').insertAfter(jQuery('li.mftopmenu'));
  jQuery('li.mfsubmenu3').insertAfter(jQuery('li.mftopmenu'));
  jQuery('li.mfsubmenu4').insertAfter(jQuery('li.mftopmenu'));
  
  jQuery('li.mfsubmenu1').not(':last').remove();
  jQuery('li.mfsubmenu2').not(':last').remove();
  jQuery('li.mfsubmenu3').not(':last').remove();
  jQuery('li.mfsubmenu4').not(':last').remove();`

Comment: glad you got a solution.. But you haven't told me that you having that class multiple times inside the DOM.. huh.. :)

Comment: HAH. Sorry. I'm completely self taught in jQuery, so my solutions aren't always... streamlined to say the least. THANK YOU AGAIN!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the `element` not a string in other words a selector string,

```
jQuery('li.mfsubmenu').after(jQuery('li.mftopmenu'));
```

Comment: Never would've thought to nest the jQuery part. That did the same as the .insertafter , it cloned them then insterted them.

Comment: @RobertFBoord What version of jquery that you are using..? It should move those elements.. can you reproduce it on a fiddle..?

Comment: @RobertFBoord what about this..? http://jsfiddle.net/2Vd4g/1/ you forgot to add the Jquery library..

Comment: Thank you! I haven't used fiddle much. It works in the fiddle, but not on the site for some reason.

Comment: Negative. It's moving the specified <li> out of the parent <ul> but not out of the parent <li>, AND it's still cloning them.

Comment: Positive, use `insertAfter` instead of `after` http://jsfiddle.net/2Vd4g/2/     is this working.?

Comment: Does the result produced from the fiddle is the expected one of yours..? Is your site live..?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and patience. jQuery has never really given me a problem that wasn't just some "dumb mistake" you know?

Comment: http://mudfactor.wpengine.com/locations/ - but you would have to emulate a mobile phone.

Comment: `jQuery('li.mfsubmenu').insertAfter(jQuery('li.mftopmenu'));` and ensure that you have used this code.?

Comment: That's the code currently in there. Even the documentation says it will insert it as a new element.

Comment: @RobertFBoord I think the problem is with the migrate library.. because in older versions(1.2.1) of jquery .insertAfter() used to clone the elements.. why are you using that migrate plugin.?

Comment: No clue haha. I'm just using Wordpress, with no alternate jQuery libraries.